# How do we deal with lightspeed self-answering?

Tags: discussion, questions

As seen in this [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67531/what-are-the-references-from-the-simpler-times-festival-shirt-from-woot), the OP answered instantly (the timestamps are the same) to his question. I left a (barely mean) comment and I downvoted the answer, but what is the appropriate behavior with this kind of reputation-grinding?

Comment: I'm more concerned about the fact that it doesn't appear to be a puzzle at all. I've VTC for that reason.

Comment: Possibly related: [How long should I wait before providing the answer to my riddle?](/q/2799/81581).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Asking and answering your own question is *encouraged* in general on the Stack Exchange network.**

Here on Stack Exchange, it's explicitly encouraged to ask and answer questions you've encountered and managed to find an answer to - that way, other people with the same question can find the answer.

It's an actual feature of the site that when you go to post a question, you can tick a checkbox to answer your own question, and you'll be able to write both the question and the answer at the same time, directly from the "Ask a Question" interface, and then post them at the exact same time. There's also a [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) about it, going into more detail.

Puzzling.SE is a bit odd, though - *most* questions here the OP *knows* the answer, and is providing a challenge to the rest of the community, so this feature is very rarely used here.

In this specific case, I don't think it's too big of a deal. The OP found a puzzle (of sorts; discussing whether it's on topic or not is an entirely different question), solved it, and decided to share it with the Puzzling.SE community. They also provided the answer they came up with at the same time, the same as they would if the puzzle was posted directly to Puzzling.SE.

**Posting the question and answer at the same time in this case is not the problem.** It's debatable whether or not it qualifies as a puzzle, but that's out of scope of this meta question.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I wanted to know :) It was the first time I saw a question-answer on PSE so I found it a bit odd.

Comment: @Saeïdryl Yes, I did it so that other people who had the same question could find an answer.  I didn't come up with it, so I thought it would be okay to post an answer.  I also felt it was puzzle-like (*I* spent a while trying to figure it out) but agree that it would be better suited elsewhere... except that it covers a variety of things (not just movies, not just sci-fi, ...) so ended up thinking that Puzzling.SE would be the most appropriate.  Anyway, sorry, I've deleted my question.

Comment: We also happen to be different in many ways from "the Stack Exchange network in general", and I think mentioning that in this meta without some explanation of how it also makes sense to Puzzling specifically is a bad argument. Even though I agree with the general sentiment that the self-answer was OK here.